# ObjectPool implementation deadlocks

Tags: c#, multithreading, monitor

I have implemented a generic ObjectPool class but have experienced that it sometime deadlocks (happens at Monitor.Wait(poolLock))

Can anyone spot the error?

```
public class ObjectPool<T> where T : new()
{
    private readonly object poolLock = new object();
    Stack<T> stack = null;

    public ObjectPool(int count)
    {
        stack = new Stack<T>(count);
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
            stack.Push(new T());
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        lock (poolLock)
        {
            //if no more left wait for one to get Pushed
            while (stack.Count < 1)
                Monitor.Wait(poolLock); 
            return stack.Pop();
        }
    }

    public void Put(T item)
    {
        lock (poolLock)
        {
            stack.Push(item);
            //If adding first send signal
            if (stack.Count == 1)
                Monitor.Pulse(poolLock); 
        }
    }
```

usage

```
        try
        {
            service = myPool.Get();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (service != null)
                myPool.Put(service);
        }
```

Comment: Nice puzzle. When it deadlocks, is that with stack.Count == 0 ?

Comment: It is Monitor.Wait(poolLock) that blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deadlock is probably happening with a `stack.Count > 0` . That means you have a Wait/Pulse problem. It is not a bad idea to always call Pulse after a Push(). Or at least when Count < 5 or so. Remember that the Wait/Pulse mechanism does not have a memory.

A scenario:

> Thread A tries to Get from an empty
>   Pool, and does a Wait()
>   Thread B tries
>   to Get from an empty Pool, and does a
>   Wait()
>
> Thread C Puts into the Pool, Does a Pulse()
>   Thread D Puts back into the Pool and does not Pulse (Count == 2)
>
> Thread A is activated and Gets its Item.
>   Thread B is left Waiting. With little hope fro recovery.

Answer (score 0):

i see it a little more clear now. I must have a reader lock, right?

```
public T Get()
{
    lock (readerLock)
    {
        lock (poolLock)
        {
            //if no more left wait for one to get Pushed
            while (stack.Count < 1)
                Monitor.Wait(poolLock);
            return stack.Pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this would not help much.

Comment: It helps in my integrationtest. Also I guess I could always Monitor.Pulse and not only when the the Count is 1.

Comment: the problem with concurrency is that it's so very hard to test.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but what about removing the "stack.Count == 1" condition and always issuing a Pulse inside of the Put function? Maybe two Puts are being called quickly in sequence and only one waiting thread is being awaken..

Answer (score 0):

Henk answered your question. Following condition is not correct:

```
if (stack.Count == 1)
```